# Regex searching a group between a group

Tags: regex

I have the regex

```
(value="(.*?)" selected="selected")
```

searching the text below

```
<select name="billing_address_id" id="billing-address-select" >
  <option value="1" selected="selected" >tim home address</option>
  <option value="2" >tim business address</option>
  <option value="" >New Address</option>
</select>

<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping-address-select" >
  <option value="1" >tim home address</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected" >tim business address</option>
  <option value="" >New Address</option>
</select>
```

It will match

```
value="1" selected="selected"
1
```

and

```
value="1" selected="selected"
2
```

how can i filter it more that it looks only inside the billing_address_id select section?

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm actually using Apache Jmeter and I want to get the billing address id with pure regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/<select.+id\s*=\s*"billing-address-select".+?value\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s+selected\s*=\s*"selected"/s
```

#### Modifiers

```
s: Dot matches new lines.
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/iF7eY5